# Cannot get group items from group in GroupBy on IMongoQueryable mongodb c# driver linq statement

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

When I try this:

```
var groupedItems = _collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(pv => pv.ArticleNumber, (k, s) => new { k, Items = s })
    .Select(group => group.Items)
    .ToList();
```

I get the following exception:

```
    System.ArgumentException: Value type of serializer is ProductVersion[] and does not match member type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[ProductVersion, ProductService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. (Parameter 'serializer')
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonMemberMap.SetSerializer(IBsonSerializer serializer)...
```

`ProductVersion` is the underlying type of the collection.

It works when I load the collection into memory via `AsEnumerable()` first and then apply the `GroupBy` and other operations but that is not an option in my scenario.
Is there any chance I can get the group items themselves in that linq statement on `IMongoQueryable`?

I am using MongoDB.Driver 2.10.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution via linq provider. You have to project the grouped Items explicitly via Select() and property by property on the group result, e.g.:

```
var groupedItems = _collection
    .AsQueryable()
    .GroupBy(pv => pv.ArticleNumber, (key, group) => new
    {
        key,
        Items = group.Select(groupItem => new ProductVersion { PropertyA = groupItem.PropertyA, ... })
    })
...
```